# Why does a number have to be encapsulated in an expression containing that number before methods can be applied to it?

Tags: javascript

`1.toString()` gives us `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

One the other hand, `(1).toString()` returns `'1'`.

Considering that `typeof 1 === typeof (1)` (both are of type `number`), why is this the case?

Comment: `1..toString()` works as does `1.0.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

In JS number literals might be both integers and floats, so probably after finding `.` after the number translator expects to parse a float, like `1.123`.